# How to update variables in Child and also Parent from Grandchild in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scenario where I have a button in the GrandChild widget that updates a variable and "sends" the updated variable to the Child.The child uses the variable it receives ,ie its used in another variable in the Child widget.The Child consequently also updates a variable and pushes it to the Parent.I am wondering if its possible to update all the variables by just one tap of a button in the GrandChild widget.

here is my GrandChild:

```
class GrandChild extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int) changeNumber;
  GrandChild(this.changeNumber, {super.key});

  @override
  State<GrandChild> createState() => _GrandChildState();
}

class _GrandChildState extends State<GrandChild> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            ++counter;
            widget.changeNumber(counter);
          });
        },
        child: const Text('Update all'));
  }
}
```

here is my Child:

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  Function(int) updateParent;//I think this will be needed to update parent
  Child(this.updateParent, {super.key});

  @override
  State<Child> createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  int childCounter = 0;
  int multiple = 1;
  int amountInChild = 0;

  fromGrandChild(int newChildCounter) {
    setState(() {
      childCounter = newChildCounter;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    amountInChild = childCounter * multiple;//this is what I need to update in parent
    return GrandChild(fromGrandChild);
  }
}
```

here is Parent:

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
   Parent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  int amountInParent = 0;
  receiveFromChild(int newFromChld) {
    amountInParent = newFromChld;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Child(receiveFromChild),
          Text(amountInParent.toString())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I do not wish to include another button in Child to update Parent, only the elevated button in GrandChild to update everywhere.

I have used call back function in GrandChild.

Comment: for these kind of scenario, using state management is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I believe all that's needed now is to call the `updateParent` in `fromGrandChild`. So

```
  fromGrandChild(int newChildCounter) {
    setState(() {
      childCounter = newChildCounter;
    });
    widget.updateParent(newChildCounter); //or whatever value you want to pass.
  }
```

Comment: tried this but it doesn't update

Comment: @EbituBonadventure I just noticed that the `Parent` is a `StatelessWidget`. It needs to be stateful so that you can call `setState` inside the `receiveFromChild`

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you can do is to declare a function in parent and pass this function to child and then to grandchild  and there you can update any value of you want